# Getting value after HTTP request response

Tags: angular, typescript, http-get

I have this working

```
findTest(name: string) {
  this.http.get<HttpResponse<any>>(destination, options).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Which works, because the response gets printed to console after it arrives.
I don't understand how to work with this, so I can do eg.

```
add() {
    const check = this.testsService.findTest(this.name);
    console.log(check);
}
```

(basically, what's the way to make `findTest()` return data and get those to `add()` and process further)

Comment: Http calls are asynchronous, so your function cannot directly return the value. It should return the `Observable` so you can subscribe to it in your calling function.

Comment: Ye, that's what I'm trying to understand, how to work with this asynchronicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `Observable` from findtest method and subscribe it to get your response.

```
findTest(name: string) {
  return this.http.get<HttpResponse<any>>(destination, options);
}

add() {
  this.findTest(this.name).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
   });
 }
```

It's better to use `services` in this kind of situation. Put `findTest` in service file and subscribe it from your component.

Answer (score 0):

```
private result;

add() {
  const check = this.testsService.findTest(this.name);
  check.subscribe(response => this.result = response); // don't forget to unsubscribe 
}
```

after that result will be in the `result` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTP call will return an observable that you need to subscribe, 
If call is successful you will get the result if not in second method error will be
thrown and finally after the call is complete you get 3rd method (it can be used if
you want to set your loader to false after your request is fully done etc). 
But you can leave it empty as well. Check the following format


 add() {
   this.testsService.findTest(this.name).subscribe(
   (data: any) => {
       console.log({data});
       this.variable_To_Store_Response= data;
   },
  (err) => { console.error(err); },
  () => { },
);

}
```